# Apple Watch app hopelessly stuck

Tags: apple-watch

The Apple Watch app on my iPhone is hopelessly stuck in the process of uninstallling a dozen apps and installing 3. It’s been at it 2 days.

I’ve followed all the suggestions I could find:
- verify Bluetooth connection
- toggle Bluetooth on and off on both
- ensure both are at the most recent OS version
- hard reset both

I noticed something very odd. The watch shows connected (green iPhone icon), and will unlock my Mac, but cannot reach Siri or ping my iPhone, and on the iPhone, Find My iPhone says the watch is offline, and the Watch app says it can't connect to the watch.

Is it possible they're still connected via bluetooth but no longer paired?

Comment: Restart your iPhone?

Comment: That was the “hard reset” step above.

Comment: Are you looking for the steps to erase the watch and start over?

Comment: I was looking for a less sledge-hammer solution, but it might come to that. I noticed something very odd. The watch shows connected (green iPhone icon), and will unlock my Mac, but cannot reach Siri or ping my iPhone, and on the iPhone, Find My iPhone says the watch is offline, and the Watch app says it can't connect to the watch. 
Is it possible they're still connected via bluetooth but no longer paired?

Comment: Yes - it's also possible one of the iCloud Keychain items that establishes the trust needs to be erased and regenerated. That's what the wipe usually entails - let's see if someone has a more elegant solution or troubleshooting procedure.

Comment: Using the sledge hammer. Can you repeat your comment as an answer so I can select it? Thanks.